# Armazenamento de vídeo

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, node.js, api, mongodb

Tem um servidor, o usuário pode colocar um título, descrição, pode opcionalmente fazer um upload de até 3 imagem e 1 vídeo. 
O título e a descrição eu sei que poderia ser armazenadas em um banco tipo mongo em JSON.
Minha dúvida é como armazenar esse vídeo e essa imagem em um banco de dados sem ter que usar um terceiro como o vimeo ou algo do tipo.

Comment: você DEVE salvar no BD o caminho para acesso as imagens e ao vídeo, e deixar o servidor fazer a stream do video pelo servidor web ou stream, e não pelo BD por conta do consumo de recursos.
o DB consome muitos recursos de um servidor para dar a saída de um arquivo, enquanto um servidor tipo apache ou nginx faz isso praticamente com poucos recursos, e o BD salva o caminho para o borwser requisitar, pode até salvar os dados pra login se for um diretório restrito....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu já utilizei gravação de imagem (nunca vídeo), utilizando um banco de dados relacional.

Basicamente vc tem que declarar a coluna como um bytea (binário) [postgres].

Depois vc tem que remontar o arquivo na hora de enviar para o cliente. Com imagens em geral nós tínhamos uma tabela com os metadados da image. Nome, extensão, mime type, nome original, tamanho em bytes.

Em meu exemplo eu utilizei o banco de dados relacional, mas também é possível gravar utilizando um banco nosql. Pois eles gravam um tipo de dados bson (que é uma representação de json em binário).